# Не определен XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Здравствуйте подскажите почему при запуске код выдает ошибку (XMLHttpRequest is not defined) у автора видео все работает?

```
let ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');
ourRequest.onload = function () {
    let ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    console.log(ourData[0]);

};
```

Comment: А вы где этот код запускаете-то?

Comment: Использую Webstorm

Comment: Ну да, в Webstorm отродясь никакого XMLHttpRequest никогда не было.

Comment: И как его тогда добавить без Node js?